# move a small circle around a big circle

Tags: math

this i an interview question i encountered with HULU.

> Given two circles, one has radius 1 and the other has radius 2. Let the small one rotate along the perimeter of the big one. how many circles will the small one rotates when it has moves one round inside the big one? and what about outside?

Comment: belongs in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The perimeter of the circle of radius 1 is 2*PI*1 and the other one is 2*PI*2.

Then when the little circles rotates inside it makes 2 round and same thing at the outside... Maybe I don't understand anything...

Answer (score 1):

how many diameters of the small circle are in one diameter of the big one?